# Filling dropdownlist with month names

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm trying to fill a dropdownlist with the names of the month. But it keeps giving me a FormatException. I'm using a similar method to fill up a dropdownlist with years, but that doesn't use the DateTime.

The error message given:

An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: De tekenreeks is niet als geldige DateTime herkend.

Rough translation: the character sequence is not a valid DateTime.

```
public void vulMaand()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            ListItem li = new ListItem();
            li.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(i.ToString() + "/1/1900").ToString("MMMM");
            li.Value = i.ToString();
            ddl_maand.Items.Add(li);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
```

and I am pretty sure that `0/1/1900` is not a valid date. You probably wanted to start your loop at `1` and end at `12`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar answer to @dotctor.

```
private void buttonLoadMonths_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBoxMonths.DisplayMember = "Value";
    comboBoxMonths.ValueMember = "Key";
    comboBoxMonths.DataSource = GetMonths();
}

private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetMonths()
{
    return Enumerable
        .Range(1, 12).Select(i => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i)))
        .ToArray();
}
```